# Strategies for selective rendering of views based on authorization in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authorization, html-rendering

I can do authorization easily on the controller actions using the Authorization attribute.
But how do I render views as easily as using Authorization attribute?

For example, if I have a menu and the user is unauthorized for certain menus, how would I hide those menu items?

Let's say I have a page that renders a table with add/edit/delete links.  I have controller actions that correspond to those links and so the unauthorized user cannot perform those actions.  But I'd like to go further by hiding them altogether.

What I have now is a spaghetti of a mess that checks for user permissions in the view - whole bunch of <% if (user.hasPermission(..) { %> ... <% } %>.  It's unruly.

What strategies are there to mitigate this mess?  Certainly I can't be the first one to have run into this dilemma.

Answer (score 0):

I think a "security trimming" ActionLink helper would solve your problem nicely:

["Security aware" action link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2721869/security-aware-action-link/2722026#2722026)

Comment: That's nice but it only works for a single link.  I'm really looking for a way to filter in or out a block of code, or a block of markup.  I know <% if (condition) { %>...<% } %> effectively does this but I feel as if it's inadequate.  Perhaps it's a different view engine that I need