# Is there a preferred approach for Roles aware links in MVC 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc

If an action has been decorated with `[Authorize(Roles="Administrators")]` is there a way to not display the link for the currently logged in user who is not in the declared role?

It seems to me that baking a lot of if statements into the view to give this kind of "selective disclosure" is contrary to the MVC way, but I'm not sure what the alternative is?

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Security aware" action link?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2721869/security-aware-action-link)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was in the related questions for your question title:

["Security aware" action link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2721869/security-aware-action-link)